# Edit and copy image in Laravel [ Can't write image data to path ]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have created the following 4 model and its table structure for my project:

**Media.php** *To upload images in app*

> Medias table structure

**id | path**

*Example of path:uploads/images/media/food-1542110154.jpg*

**Post.php**  *Create post*

> Posts table structure

**id | title | content**

**FeaturedImage.php** *Featured image for post*

> Posts table structure

**id | post_id| path**

> Post model and FeaturedImage model are in a one-to-one relationship

**UploadImage.php** *To resize the uploaded image and move it to another directory. This model doesn't have migration and controller*

Code snippet from `PostsController.php` to create the post

```
use App\UploadImage;
use App\Media;
class PostController extends Controller
{
private $imagePath= "uploads/images/post/";
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->content = $request->content;
    $post->save();

    $media = Media::find($request->featured);
    if (!File::exists($this->imagePath)) {
        File::makeDirectory($this->imagePath);
    }
    $upload = new UploadImage;
    $image= $upload->uploadSingle($this->banner, $media->path, 400,300);
    $post->image()->save(new FeaturedImage([
        'path' => $image
    ]));

}
  Session::flash('success', 'Post created sucessfully !');
  return redirect()->route('post.index');
}
```

Code snippet from `UploadImage.php`

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\Facades\ImageOptimizer;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class UploadImage extends Model
{

  public  function  uploadSingle($savePath, $image,$width,$height)
 {
    Image::make(public_path($image))->fit($width, $height)->save($savePath);
    ImageOptimizer::optimize($savePath);
    return $savePath;
 }  
}
```

In my Laravel app, I'm trying to edit dimension of the already uploaded image with method written in `UploadImage.php` and save edited image in `post` directory and save its path in `featured_images` table.

But I've been getting **Can't to write image data to path ** error.

I would be very thankful if anyone could point out the mistakes that I've made.

> Please do not mark this as duplicate content. As I've been gone through almost all posts related to this kind of error and they have been no help to me.

Comment: forget about my previous comment, what is `$media->path`? Shouldn't it be `$this->imagePath` ?

Comment: public_path to save the images ? usually we use storage_path ... public path is http's user writable ?

Comment: @TahaPaksu `$media->path` is the path of original image that has been alreadey uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaked few lines in my UploadImage.php model and got it solved.

```
public  function  uploadSingle($savePath, $image,$width,$height)
{
    $filename = basename($image);
    $location = $savePath . $filename;
    Image::make($image)->save($location);
    ImageOptimizer::optimize($location);
    return $location;
}
```